# runtime error 91 - access excel interaction

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am running an access VBA code to open Excel, make minor amendments to some graphs and save them as bmps. It’s working well 98% time. However, every now and then I get the following error at line “`Selection.Left = 320`”:

> Run time error ‘91’:
>   Object variable or with block variable not set

Second minor issue I would like to solve is that every time I open any other excel document after running this macro the excel document used by this macro is automatically opened as well, no idea why.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If [Forms]![Detail]![Qualification Documents].[Value] <> "" Then
         Dim octopus As String
         octopus = ([Forms]![Detail]![Qualification Documents].[Value])
         Set objExcelApp = New Excel.APPLICATION
         Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="Path\" & octopus & " ", ReadOnly:=True)
         'Set ws = wb.Sheets("SheetX")
          wb.APPLICATION.DisplayAlerts = False
          wb.Sheets("SheetX").Select
  x = 1
  While x < 4
  wb.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(x).Activate
  With wb.ActiveChart.Parent
     .Height = 500 ' resize
     .Width = 1200 ' resize
     .Top = 100    ' reposition
     .Left = 100   ' reposition
  End With

                 On Error GoTo here:
here:
wb.ActiveChart.Legend.Select
Selection.Left = 320
Selection.Top = 380
Selection.Height = 35
Selection.Width = 600
wb.ActiveChart.Export "X:\Assembly\CAPEX 2013\drilling database\graph" & x & ".bmp"
x = x + 1
Wend
wb.Close
Set objExcelApp = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `Selection` is invalid from time to time, i.e. while running the macro, the selection is somehow invalidated, e.g. by a user clicking into the Excel window or something similar. Try using the `Left` property of the graph or object directly, without using `Selection.`:

```
x = 1
While x < 4
    With wb.Sheets("SheetX").ChartObjects(x)
        .Parent.Height = 500 ' resize
        .Parent.Width = 1200 ' resize
        .Parent.Top = 100    ' reposition
        .Parent.Left = 100   ' reposition

        .Legend.Left = 320
        .Legend.Top = 380
        .Legend.Height = 35
        .Legend.Width = 600
    End With
Wend
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Howerver, I have already worked around the problem so I will not be able to test your suggestion on the particular problem.